# How to make a screen shot of my actual window

Tags: delphi, screenshot, delphi-2009

I defined a Tactionlist which contains all actions to show/hide my forms. This could be modal (showmodal) or non modal (visible:=true). I found some code to catch the screen shots by this:

```
procedure GetScreenShot(shotType: TScreenShotType; var img: TJpegImage);
var
  w,h: integer;
  DC: HDC;
  hWin: Cardinal;
  r: TRect;
  tmpBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  hWin := 0;
  case shotType of
    sstActiveWindow:
      begin  //This is what I use
        //only the active window
        hWin := GetForegroundWindow;
        dc := GetWindowDC(hWin);
        GetWindowRect(hWin,r);
        w := r.Right - r.Left;
        h := r.Bottom - r.Top;
      end;  //sstActiveWindow
    sstActiveClientArea:
      begin
      end;  //sstActiveClientArea
    sstPrimaryMonitor:
      begin
      end;  //sstPrimaryMonitor
    sstDesktop:
      begin
      end;  //sstDesktop
    else begin
      Exit;
    end;  //case else
  end;  //case

  //convert to jpg
  tmpBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    tmpBmp.Width := w;
    tmpBmp.Height := h;
    BitBlt(tmpBmp.Canvas.Handle,0,0,tmpBmp.Width,
      tmpBmp.Height,DC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    img.Assign(tmpBmp);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(hWin,DC);
    FreeAndNil(tmpBmp);
  end;  //try-finally
end;
```

My "scan" routine is as follows:

```
for ACnt := 0 to GenActions.ActionCount - 1 do
    begin
    try
    LogBook.ML(Format('%d. Aktion %s gestartet',[ACnt,quotedstr(GenActions.Actions[ACnt].Name)]));
    if GenActions.Actions[ACnt].Tag > 0 then
         begin  // Action is ready for test
         TAction(GenActions.Actions[ACnt]).checked:=true;
         if GenActions.Actions[ACnt].Execute then
              begin
              LogBook.ML(Format('%d. Aktion %s erfolgreich ausgeführt',[ACnt,quotedstr(GenActions.Actions[ACnt].Name)]));
              if SaveScreens then   // var boolean
                   begin
                   img:=TJPEGImage.Create;
                   try
                   GetScreenShot(sstActiveWindow,img);         
                   img.SaveToFile(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Optionen.PictPfad.Text)+inttostr(ACnt)+'.jpg');
                   finally
                        img.Free;
                        end;
                   end;
              repeat
              sleep(100);
              Application.ProcessMessages;
              until not DM_Gen.TestTimer.Enabled ;  //for modal windows a timer sends modalresult:=mrcancel
              end;
         end
    else
         begin
         LogBook.ML(Format('%d Aktion %s nicht getestet',[ACnt,quotedstr(GenActions.Actions[ACnt].Name)]));
         end;
    except
         on E: Exception do
         LogBook.ML(Format('%d. Aktion hat Fehler %s gemeldet',[ACnt,E.Message]));
         end;
    end;
finally
    LogBook.ML('Testlauf beendet');
    end;
```

When I run this code I get for about the first 150 actions the mainform, then some other forms like the logbook or the browser or ... Nearly never the form I want.

I found some posts which recommended the use of "findwindow". Here is my problem that I don't know the exact caption of the window, because in all windows the caption is modified in the onshow event in order to show actual information.

Any ideas how can catch my actual opened window?

So a problem is to understand how my actions work. Here two typical examples:

```
procedure TDM_Gen.VALstVisActExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Sender is TAction then
    begin   // set some properties
    end;
ListeVeranst_2.Visible:=VALstVisAct.Checked;
end;

procedure TDM_Gen.NewVAActExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
NewVA : TNewVeranstaltung;
begin
if Sender <> nil then
    begin
    if Sender is TButton then
         begin   //do something depending on who fired
         end;
    end;
try
NewVA:=TNewVeranstaltung.Create(nil);
case NewVA.ShowModal of
mrOk:
    begin    // e.g. refresh some lists
    end;
mrCancel:    
    begin    // clean up
    end;
end;

finally
    NewVA.Free;
    end;
end;
```

The caption of the window is set during the onshow event by:

```
caption:=Format('This is window %s %s',[Param1, Param2]);
```

Comment: If you don't know which window you want, what chance do we have?

Comment: I know which window I want. The one which is made visible by the action

Comment: So what's stopping you screenshotting that window?

Comment: This is my question.I don't know. 
If I try to get it by "getforeground" as shown in the code above I get in the most cases the mainform, the focus maybe left the opened window and went back to the mainform. I have no idea. So maybe there is an other way to find the window. When I execute the action in some cases the window is create during run time, so I don't know the caption (or how to get) and...

Comment: So you've got actions which don't know what they are doing.. Change them code, so that you have a reference to the created form.

Comment: This is long shoot advice, but adding `Application.ProcessMessages` after you execute your action and before you try to capture foreground window might do the trick. But your best option is to store the reference, like others have said.

Comment: ProcessMessages is bad advice.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I agree with David. The use of `Application.ProcessMessages` won't do much good here.

Comment: @ChristineRoss You say you are showing and hiding your own forms with Actions and you want to make a screenshot of those forms when the action is executed. You can easily get handle to the window of the form your action has just shown or created by reading if from that forms `Handle` property. Now in case of modal forms you would have to execute your screenshot code from within the modal form code or the form might be destroyed before you try to do screenshot of it. For this you can create custom routine which will show them modally and take screenshot right away.

Comment: How about you capture the whole desktop, and later decide what to keep.

Comment: You shouldn't have to "find" your window if you're the one who created it. We can't see how you're creating them, but you should be saving a reference to it, and refer to its handle directly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never said it is good advice. But code in question already has one, it is hard to say what is actually happening, and it is quite possible that capturing wrong window is due to some windows messaging/timing issue. In that case `ProcessMessage` _could be_ quick fix. If it works it could certainly be less work than going through all code making changes to store references (and I also said that would be the best option)

Comment: I updated my question and put in some example code for the actions.

My two questions remain:

Why is this window no more on forefront?

How can I get the handle of the window by some other actions?

Comment: Because you are calling ShowModal in your Execute. By the time Execute returns and you try to capture screen shot, your form has already been closed. Just to set record straight, in this case ProcessMessages I suggested before, as well as keeping references would not help you.

Comment: You would have to initiate capturing screen shot from within your modal form. Also in that case you would actually know which window you need to capture, so you don't have to try to find it.

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar, your first statement is not true, when the execute returns the modal form and also the non modal forms are still visible. To close the modal form I use a timer (see program 2 the "until" clause waits until the timer is off). After that the form is closed.

The second statement gives the solution I wanted to avoid. I have to add code for screen captioning in every action or maybe better in every form (after onshow). But maybe it is a good idea to enclose it in a {IFDEF Test} directive. But the getscreenshot function looks so easy and harmless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem you are facing is due to `ShowModal` method that is blocking call. That means that all subsequent code after that call will start executing after the form is closed.

Code flow in following simplified example:

```
  MyAction.Execute;
  CaptureScreen;

procedure TSomeForm.MyActionExecute(Sender: TObject);
var frm: TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    frm.ShowModal; // this call blocks execution of subsequent code in this method until form is closed
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

will be `MyAction.Execute -> frm.ShowModal -> frm.Close -> frm.Free -> CaptureScreen`

You will have to initiate screen capturing from within your modal form in order to capture its screen.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced by your explanation. It sounds possible for modal forms. I will check it.
But what is with the non modal forms. Here should my code work. But it doesn't work with both

Comment: OK, you are right for modal forms. The Logbook entry for the successful end of action (snipplet 2 line 10) is allways after the closing of the form, therefore will the screencapture code excuted when the form is no more there.